# Custom Tooltips JQVMap

Tags: jquery, jqvmap

I have a JQVMap that is currenting visualizing some data.  Each country on the map is a specific color and has a specific number from 0-10.

I know how to show default tooltips, you simply switch the `showTooltip` to `true`, and it shows the country names `onmouseover`.  How can I also show the number corresponding to each country on these tooltips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

there is an event for onLabelShow.  From the documentation...

> **onLabelShow** function(event, label, code)
>
> Callback function which will be called before label is shown. Label
>   DOM object and country code will be passed to the callback as
>   arguments.

Maybe something like this could work for you?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
                map: 'usa_en',
                selectedRegion: 'co',
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                color: '#E6E7E9',
                hoverColor: '#03235E',
                enableZoom: false,
                showTooltip: true,
                onLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
                    if (states.toLowerCase().indexOf(code) <= -1) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    } else if (label[0].innerHTML == "Colorado") {
                        label[0].innerHTML = label[0].innerHTML + " - The state where I live!!";
                    }
                },                
            });
        });
```